# Reversing a linked list without modifying the head pointer

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, palindrome

I was writing a program to check if a singly linked list is palindrome or not.
My approach was as follows:

1. Create a singly linked list
2. Reverse the list and store it in another variable
3. Compare the two.

The reverse operation modifies the head pointer. So as not to modify the head pointer, I create a `temp` variable to point to head and reverse the list with the same and return the `temp` pointer. The operation is as follows:

```
struct node* reverse()
{
    struct node *temp=head;
    struct node *curr=temp, *prev=NULL, *next=NULL;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
          next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    temp = prev;
    return temp;
}
```

Now, my palindrome function is implemented as follows:

```
int isPalindrome()
{
    struct node *temp=head, *rev=head;
    rev = reverse();
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data != rev->data)
            return 0;
        temp = temp->next;
        rev = rev->next;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If the reversed list and the original list nodes don't match, return 0. Otherwise return 1.

It worked for a few test cases. But when the list was 1->4->3->2->1. It returned 1 but it should have returned 0.

On working out, I found, the `rev` function modified the head pointer. And now, my list had only one node.

The output is shown below:
[image]

1. The first list is printing with the head pointer **unmodified**
2. The second list is reversed list
3. The third list is printing the original list after calling the `reverse` function

Comment: Well, the reversed and original lists use the same nodes, which can have only one orientation. When you rearrange them in reverse order, the original order is lost. If you want to have two different lists, you must make a "deep copy", i.e. create new nodes as clones of the existing ones.

Comment: Best design would be to use the double linked list ,we can reduce the step of reversing .

Answer (score 3):

After reversing your original head points to the last element in the reversed list, which is why you are seeing only one element in the 3rd output. There a few options for you:

1. Use a double linked list. Traverse from head and tail and the same time in opposite directions.
2. Copy the original list before reversing and compare the two lists.
3. Use a stack or some other data structure to help (similar to option 2 above).
4. Modify your algorithm to use only the original list.

Comment: As you said I already copied the original list into the variable `temp` in the method `isPalindrome()`. But yet things don't work out

Comment: The variable `temp` is just a copy of the head pointer. You will have to do a deep copy, which means to duplicate all the nodes and create a new list instead of just manipulating the original one.

Answer (score 2):

It is evident that function `reverse` is wrong  because it shall build a new list. This means that it has to create new nodes for the reversed list based on the nodes of the original list. That is it has to allocate its nodes in memory using standard function `malloc`.

Also it is more logically consistent to define a function that will compare two lists. Using this function you can say whether a list is a palindrome.

Here is a demonstrative program that you can use as a sample for your own program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void push_front( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *n = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    n->data = data;
    n->next = *head;

    *head = n;
}

void display( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->data );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

struct node * reverse_copy( struct node *head )
{
    struct node *rev_head = NULL;

    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        push_front( &rev_head, head->data ); 
    }

    return rev_head;
}

int equal( struct node *head1, struct node *head2 )
{
    while ( head1 != NULL && head2 != NULL && head1->data == head2->data )
    {
        head1 = head1->next;
        head2 = head2->next;
    }

    return head1 == NULL && head2 == NULL;
}

void free_list( struct node **head )
{
    struct node *n = *head;

    while ( n != NULL )
    {
        struct node *tmp = n;
        n = n->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    *head = NULL;
}

struct node *head;

int main(void) 
{
    push_front( &head, 1 );
    push_front( &head, 2 );
    push_front( &head, 3 );
    push_front( &head, 4 );
    push_front( &head, 1 );

    display( head );

    struct node *rev_head = reverse_copy( head );

    if ( equal( head, rev_head ) )
    {
        printf( "The list is a palindrome\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The list is not a palindrome\n" );
    }

    free_list( &head );
    free_list( &rev_head );

    push_front( &head, 1 );
    push_front( &head, 2 );
    push_front( &head, 3 );
    push_front( &head, 2 );
    push_front( &head, 1 );

    display( head );

    rev_head = reverse_copy( head );

    if ( equal( head, rev_head ) )
    {
        printf( "The list is a palindrome\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The list is not a palindrome\n" );
    }

    free_list( &head );
    free_list( &rev_head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 4 3 2 1 
The list is not a palindrome
1 2 3 2 1 
The list is a palindrome
```